# Maclaurin series for $f(x)=\cosh(3x^4)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

is there a faster way to calculate the first $4$ non-zero terms of the Maclaurin series for $f(x)=\cosh(3x^4)$ rather than differentiating the whole function over and over?

ie. does the Maclaurin series of $\cosh(x)$ help reach the answer faster?

Comment: Well, of course. You just take the Maclaurin series of $\cosh y$ and plug in a $"(3x^4)"$ every time you see an "$y$". Of course, you have to keep in mind that coefficients and exponents slightly change accordingly when you run the calcs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, the Maclaurin series of $\cosh(x)$ does help find the answer faster.  See that if we have

$$\cosh(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$

Then it follows that we have

$$\cosh(3x^4)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(3x^4)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n3^nx^{4n}$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that

$$
{\rm cosh}t = \frac{1}{2}(e^{t} + e^{-t}) \tag{1}
$$

and

$$
e^t = \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!} \tag{2}
$$

Replacing (2) in (1):

$$
{\rm cosh}t = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^n + (-t)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!}
$$

This last step is because all odd terms cancel out in the numerator while the even terms add up. Now, setting $t = 3x^4$ you get

$$
{\rm cosh}(3x^4) = \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{(3x^4)^{2n}}{(2n)!} = \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{9^n x^{8n}}{(2n)!}
$$

Comment: doesn't help in the slightest lol

Comment: @ConnorGaughan Hope it helps now

Comment: ah yes i see, thanks.